# list.remove(x): x not in list in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to make a program that will remove 0 from the list la, but when I try to run the program I get the "Exception has occurred: ValueError list.remove(x): x not in list" error. How do i fix this?

```
s = '1 0 2 0 3'
la = s.split()
la.remove(0)
print(la)
```

Comment: I see you're using `s.split`, which means `la` is a list of strings. You are trying to remove an int value from a list of strings. So that's why x is not in list.

Comment: by adding 0 to the list, haha. Not an expert on stackoverflow but this isn't really the kind of questions you should be asking here (as evident by the downvotes)...

Comment: @RobinDillen that's why people should use typing in their projects.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you have a list of strings and you are trying to remove an integer.

If you want to remove only the first occurrence you, should replace it with:

`la.remove('0')`

for all occurnaces:

`la[:] = (value for value in la if value != '0')`

Answer (score 0):

That is because the list `la` consists of `str` element(s) and you are trying to remove integer `0` from it which it does not contain. Reminding you that `0` and `'0'` are not the same thing, they are `int` and `str` respectively.

Let's remove `'0'` from list `la`

```py
s = '1 0 2 0 3'
la = s.split()
la.remove("0")
print(la) # ['1', '2', '0', '3']
```

This as expected removed the first occurrence of `'0'` in `la`.

If you rather be interested in making the list `la` a list containing integers then

```py
la = list(map(int, la))
```

Is what you're looking for.